Is plant perception a personification?
I read this wikipage and it seems like 'reacting to stimuli' is being called perception (saññā). Is 'reacting to stimuli' perception, or is perception itself stimuli? To me, the article implies perception is the condition for expression, i.e. a reaction.  Do you agree that for a plant the stimulus-response is a single unitary movement (no karmaphala) and there is no intermission (of perception)? Is it more likely a projection of human knowledge - the personification of a plant?
A perception has a result (Karmaphala). The results are perception are explained as such:

"And what is the result of perception? Perception has communication by
speech as its result, I tell you. However a person per ceives
something, that is how he expresses it: 'I have this sort of
perception.' This is called the result of perception.

Here is a quote for BSE:

"In the scriptures we have the word sañña. Sañña means distinguishing,
putting a label, telling difference, making distinction,
discriminating."

Is labeling perception or the result of perception?

cyberspace is a terrible thing to waste

I think you're asking something like -- "If a plant reacts, is that like a bouncing ball i.e. it does that without thinking? Or is the reaction a result of a perception (e.g. of pain or threat etc.)?"
Firstly I agree with you -- i.e. that using the word "perception" in the article seems to be "begging the question" i.e. assuming the answer (without any proof).
Second, if I try Google e.g. https://www.google.com/search?q=buddhism+sentience+plants it suggests that the Early Buddhist Texts are not explicit on that subject -- so some later authors (theorists?) try to derive an answer "logically".
There's some related topic on this site:

Why are plants not sentient beings?


Incidentally I don't think that "personification" is always wrong. Personification is inherent in e.g. "Do unto others as you would have them do unto you", i.e. it's a worldly/relative doctrine -- that may be important for the sake of teaching morality -- even if the concept is "empty" in some higher sense. We personify people to some extent and therefore (learn to) behave with some respect -- and enlarge on that concept (from "person" to "sentient being") to extend the same courtesy toward animals (and even other non-material beings).

If I had to quote a source from the Early Buddhist Texts I point to e.g. the notion that "devas" are associated with trees -- they're the 'spirit which inhabits trees' who become homeless if the tree is destroyed:

Once, a bhikkhu from Alavi wanted to build a monastery for himself and so he began to cut down a tree. The deva dwelling in that tree (rukkha devata) tried to stop him, saying that she and her infant son had nowhere to go. Failing to stop the bhikkhu she put her son on a branch, hoping that it would stop him from felling the tree. By then, the bhikkhu was already swinging his axe and he could not stop it in time and unintentionally cut off an arm of the child. Seeing her child being harmed in this way, the mother flew in a rage and was about to kill the bhikkhu. As she raised her hands to strike the bhikkhu, she suddenly checked herself and thought, "If I were to kill a bhikkhu, I would be killing one who observes the moral precepts (sila); in that case, I would surely suffer in niraya. Other guardian devas of the trees would be following my example and other bhikkhus would also be killed. But this bhikkhu has a master; I must go and see his master." So she went weeping to the Buddha and related all that had happened.
Dhammapada Verse 222

Perhaps that's analogous to contemporary beliefs/analogies about people being "housed" in their own bodies:

Oh house-builder! You are seen, you shall build no house (for me) again.
Dhammapada Verse 154


good article. makes me wonder the diff between mind and the aggregate of consciousness, perhaps plant lack the ability or chance to grasp at the aggregates, hence no mind...

That’s the post I read of rubrn2020…interesting the article defines bhuta as meaning ‘being’ like Buddha was  describable as yathabhuta*

The article says: "Plant perception is the ability of plants to sense and respond to the environment by adjusting their morphology and physiology".
From the viewpoint of Buddhism, the perception would be the "sensing" and not the "responding".

While perception in Buddhism is certainly "distinguishing", whether it refers to "labelling" is questionable.

It perceives, it perceives': Thus, friend, it is said to be
'perception.' And what does it perceive? It perceives blue. It
perceives yellow. It perceives red. It perceives white. 'It perceives,
it perceives': Thus it is said to be 'perception.'
MN 43


The world can crumble down, this is why it is called the world (SN 35.82). I believe 'sañña' is a matter of the world.
Fame and infamy which are worldly matters (AN 8.6)  are, in my view, examples of sañña. I understand sañña as a recognition of "being such and such while not being such and such". It's one of the acquisitions which we can't see as fallible, difficulty, and impersonal.
I like to read MN 43 as saying "It distinguishes blue, it distinguishes yellow...". 'Perception' makes people think in biological terms unlike 'distinction'.

Fame & infamy sound like matters of sankhara rather than sanna

Any acquisition is sankhara, fabrications. For example, gain and loss are sankhara. They sound important but are hollow like banana tree for the wise.

@mjaviem now i think perception is limited to the mind, so it cannot be biological for me, tmrw is another day.

@mjaviem maybe i'm wrong, perhaps plants do have cetana (intelligence), and we are the only ones using it wrongly..

Perception clearly is related to what is perceived through 6 senses ( mind , body , tongue , nose , ear , eyes) … There are many ways of perceiving. Each perception can be good , bad , ugly , neutral. Each perception can be valuable, worthless, neutral. Each perception can be sexy , boring , disgusting. Each perception can be perfect , defective and neutral and so on…. None of the perceptions are permanent. Perceptions arise , change while persisting and they vanish too. Perceptions by definition takes cognisance on things as they are as defined in so many ways above. Abandon all perceptions and seek refuge in impermanence of all conditioned phenomena. And realising all perceptions are not self( perceptions which occurs as me , mine or myself as not self)
We react to stimuli as defined above. Stimuli is itself not perception but our categorisation of it in so many ways.

A sentient being is found when you have all five aggregates (SN 5.10) and a sense of clinging to the self (SN 23.2). In other words, a sentient being is found when you have the five clinging aggregates (SN 22.48). The sentient being is also the person who is the carrier of the burden (SN 22.22).
SN 22.79 has some definitions of the five aggregates.
Form as an aggregate is what the plant has and what a stone has, too. It's the physical form, made of physical elements.
Feeling as an aggregate refers to sensing. We can argue that plants can sense their environment.
Perception as an aggregate refers to memory and recognizing previously identified objects. This is based on the explanation in the Abhidhamma.
We can argue that plants could have perception. For e.g. plants grow towards the source of light. If light is available only in a certain direction, the plant would slowly bend towards it as it grows. Of course, plants don't have memory like animals do.
Plants do not have any kind of consciousness or mental formations based on the definitions of SN 22.79, so they are neither sentient beings nor persons.
The easiest way to understand this is that plants do not have a mind, so they can neither be sentient beings nor persons.

do u think imputed consciousness reflects itself on matter?
